# Need to remove spaces in between days and add comma using sql

Tags: sql, oracle, trim, character-trimming

I would like to remove spaces and add commas in between the data using SQL. Like if I have column with the data `' mon  tue  wed thu '` I need it to be like `'mon,tue,wed,thu'`

Can someone help me with this.

Comment: MySQL and Oracle are two different RDBMS; which are you using?

Comment: i'm Using Oracle

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you can use:

```sql
SELECT TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM REGEXP_REPLACE(value, '\s+', ',')) AS replaced_value
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT ' mon tue wed thu ' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> | REPLACED_VALUE |
> | --- |
> | mon,tue,wed,thu |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9f97f546eb506d91a0276846f91c25ca)*

Comment: I have a lot of data in the column like  c1 = '   mon   tue   wed   '  and c2 = '   mon   tue   wed   thu   fri   '   and c3 = '   mon  tue   '   and so on... 

So how can i you use the same in a query?

Comment: Convert the solution about to a generic function

Comment: @Dug Just copy-paste the code for the different columns and change the column name.